# Trying to automate excel vba code for every one hour. I tried giving wait time, but after a day or so, it starts lagging

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate excel vba code for every one hour. I tried giving wait time, but after a day or so, it starts lagging. I want my code to run every 0th minute of every hour of every day. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub timer()

        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:45:00"), "Button1_Click"

End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()

    Call SftpPut

End Sub

Sub SftpPut()

    '--takes here approximately 10-15mins to run few other things and then calls timer.
    Call timer

End Sub
```

Comment: try vbscript with a scheduled task in windows to start the script every 45 min.There you can do `SftpPut()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to have `Application.Ontime` run at the start of the next hour, instead of guessing when that will be. This calculation does that:

```
 Application.OnTime CDate(Int(DateAdd("h",1,Now())*24)/24), "Button1_Click"
```

Alternatively, you could calculate the next hour with three DateAdd functions:

```
Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", -Second(Now()), DateAdd("n", -Minute(Now()), DateAdd("h", 1, Now()))), "Button1_Click"
```

Comment: just to notice that the first calculation returns +2 hours if made after the 30th minute of the current hour

Comment: @user3598756, woops, I put up a draft version. Supposed to be `Int`. I'll fix it, thanks!